# jquery autocomplete accept without selecting from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Im using autocomplete plugin to show the user options to choose from when typing a word.

**The problem here is:**

This code won't allow the word if the user types correctly a word that match the avaible tags without clicking on the showed items on the dropdown.

How can I fix it?, this is what I have.

```
$( "#fuente" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) {
                $("#fuente").val("");
                $("#fuente").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#fuente').removeClass('fuenteboxCheck');
                $('#fuente').addClass('fuenteboxNCheck');
            } 
            else {
                $('#fuente').removeClass('fuenteboxNCheck');
                $('#fuente').addClass('fuenteboxCheck');
            }
        }
    });
```

is there an easy way to fix this?, pls halp.
thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. so I did some more research and found a very good solution to my problem.
Hope this helps someone else with this problem.

```
var lastValue;

        var lastValue;

        $("#fuente").autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          select: function(event, ui) {
                lastValue = ui.item.value;
            },
          response: function(event, ui) {
            //lastValue = ui.content.length > 0 ? ui.content[0].value : '';
            if(ui.content.length > 0){
                lastValue = ui.content[0].value;
                $('#fuente').removeClass('fuenteboxNCheck');
                $('#fuente').addClass('fuenteboxCheck');
            }
            else{
                lastValue = '';
                $('#fuente').removeClass('fuenteboxCheck');
                $('#fuente').addClass('fuenteboxNCheck');
            }
          }
        });           
        $("#fuente").on('blur', function() {
            $(this).val(lastValue);
        });lse{
                lastValue = '';
                $('#fuente').removeClass('fuenteboxCheck');
                $('#fuente').addClass('fuenteboxNCheck');
            }   
          }
        });
        $("#fuente").on('blur', function() {
            $(this).val(lastValue);

        });
      });
```

thnx.